# PDO ODBC: Strings with spanish characters get blanked, but only on CLI

Tags: php, pdo, command-line, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to connect to a IBM DB2 database using PHP, more precisely pdo_odbc. The idea is to move some data between databases, from DB2 to postgre/mysql. I SELECT in DB2, construct a INSERT statement with the fetched data, and execute it in the other database.

This works "almost" perfectly: it only works perfectly on the browser. If I execute the script on the command line, it will blank any string that contains spanish characters. The string doesn't get truncated, doesn't convert it to junk characters and the driver doesn't inform of any error, it just don't work. The string is just blank immediatly after fetching the result set. This happens both in development and production in the same way. And since this is a crontabbed script that does nightly migrations of data, it must be executed on the command line.

**Operating System:** Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, using bash

**PHP version:** PHP 7.3.3-1 in development, PHP 7.0.33-0 in production

**Locale:** es_ES.UTF-8 in development, en_US.UTF-8 in production

**IBM i Version:** It varies from V7R2 to V7R4.

**CCSID of the DB2 table:** 284 (Spanish EBCDIC).

**Connection string and attributes:**

```php
$this->link = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};"
                                . "SYSTEM=".$GLOBALS['DB2System'].";"
                                . "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;",
                                $GLOBALS['DB2User'], $GLOBALS['DB2Pass']);
            $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);
            $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);
```

**cwbnltbl output:** "Linux locale codeset=UTF-8 ccsid=1208".

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: The value of LANG is the one I posted in Locale. About the client, I don't know how to check it, I installed the "IBM i Access ODBC Driver" on both machines.
EDIT: I'm afraid that's not the problem. The strings get blanked even if I manually run the script.

Comment: What is the version of the i-series? (ask your admin).  What is the CCSID of the table containing the Spanish characters?  what attributes do you specify on the connection-string, or in the user profile, or in the DSN (if any) for the job ccsid?

Comment: if you run your query via `isql` does the codepage conversion work correctly?
To find the current mapping  between your locale and the CCSID , what is the output of `cwbnltbl`?
(e.g `/opt/ibm/iaccess/bin/cwbnltbl` ). You can override the CCSID mapping via configuration in your i access config file. You can use the history log and `cwbtrc` to investigate conversion problems, just follow the instructions in the docs.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I'll answer your questions.
IBM i version: It varies. Our own IBM i it's V7R3, some clients use V7R2 or V7R4.
CCSID of the table: 284 (Spanish EBCDIC).
Attributes specified in the connection: Using PDO, I set the following.
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION |
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=0 |
    PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT=0 |.
I can't get isql to work, sorry, I surely configured my obdc.ini wrong.
cwbnltbl gives me: "Linux locale codeset=UTF-8 ccsid=1208".
I'll try to use cwbntrc.

Comment: You need to find the differences between the working case (browser) and the failing case (cli). Some environment variable or other configuration differences.

Comment: I already know that there must be a difference, but I don't know where else to look, or what component or configuration could be the more likely suspect.

Comment: When run on the browser, is it on same hostname as when run in CLI? Is it same userid/account? Use phpinfo, or change script to dump the output of getenv() array  for working and failing cases and compare.